GEE - Mean Cloudiness in a given time range, Sentinel producing multiple points for each day
I am trying to create a plot that represents mean cloudiness against day of year using Sentinel-2. As the plot shows, there are multiple points for a given day and it's very choppy. Should Sentinel be outputting multiple points, and if so, how would I simplify that even further so that I'm only receiving one averaged point for each day to represent mean cloudiness?

var startDate = '2021-10-15';
var endDate = '2021-11-15';


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.filterBounds(UCRB);


var cloudState = dataset.select('QA60');


// Function to calculate cloudiness for each image
var calculateCloudiness = function(image) {
var QA = image.select('QA60');


var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
};

var cloudStateBits = bitwiseExtract(QA, 10, 11);
var cloudMask = cloudStateBits.gte(1);

// Reduce to the mean cloudiness at the specified point
var meanCloudiness = cloudMask.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: UCRB,
scale: 1000,
maxPixels: 1e9
});

// Return the cloudiness as a new property of the image
return image.set('cloudiness', meanCloudiness.get('QA60'));
};


// Apply the cloudiness calculation to each image in the collection
var cloudinessCollection = cloudState.map(calculateCloudiness);


var addDate = function(image) {
// Get the image ID (system
var id = image.id();
// Extract date from the image ID, assuming format 'YYYYMMDD'
var dateString = ee.String(id).slice(0, 8); // Extract 'YYYYMMDD'
// Parse date as 'YYYYMMDD' format
var date = ee.Date.parse('YYYYMMdd', dateString);
// Return the image with added date property
return image.set('date', date);
};

cloudinessCollection = cloudinessCollection.map(addDate);
// Reduce to get the mean cloudiness over the period of interest
var meanCloudiness = cloudinessCollection.aggregate_mean('cloudiness');

print('Mean cloudiness over the period:', meanCloudiness);

// To visualize or further analyze, you can export the results
// Export the cloudiness time series to a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: cloudinessCollection,
description: 'CloudinessTimeSeries',
fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
features: cloudinessCollection,
xProperty: 'date',
yProperties: ['cloudiness']

})

var chartStyle = {
title: 'Sentinel Mean Cloudiness (Oct - Nov 2021)',
hAxis: {
title: 'Date',
},
vAxis: {
title: 'Mean Cloudiness',
}
};

chart.setOptions(chartStyle);
print(chart)



Depending on the size of your region of interest, there may be more than 1 Sentinel-2 image for a given day. Thus, you may see multiple data points for each day.
To get only 1 averaged point per each day, I've averaged the cloudiness for each day.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/76e6bd6a8fe55150315f5976fa9f307c
var startDate = '2021-10-15';
var endDate = '2021-11-15';


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.filterBounds(UCRB);

var cloudState = dataset.select('QA60');

// Function to calculate cloudiness for each image
var calculateCloudiness = function(image) {
var QA = image.select('QA60');


var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
};

var cloudStateBits = bitwiseExtract(QA, 10, 11);
var cloudMask = cloudStateBits.gte(1);

// Reduce to the mean cloudiness at the specified point
var meanCloudiness = cloudMask.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: UCRB,
scale: 1000,
maxPixels: 1e9
});

// Return the cloudiness as a new property of the image
return image.set('cloudiness', meanCloudiness.get('QA60'));
};


// Apply the cloudiness calculation to each image in the collection
var cloudinessCollection = cloudState.map(calculateCloudiness);


var addDate = function(image) {
// Get the image ID (system
var id = image.id();
// Extract date from the image ID, assuming format 'YYYYMMDD'
var dateString = ee.String(id).slice(0, 8); // Extract 'YYYYMMDD'
// Parse date as 'YYYYMMDD' format
var date = ee.Date.parse('YYYYMMdd', dateString);
// Return the image with added date property
return image.set('date', date);
};

cloudinessCollection = cloudinessCollection.map(addDate);
// Reduce to get the mean cloudiness over the period of interest
var meanCloudiness = cloudinessCollection.aggregate_mean('cloudiness');

print('Mean cloudiness over the period:', meanCloudiness);

// To visualize or further analyze, you can export the results
// Export the cloudiness time series to a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: cloudinessCollection,
description: 'CloudinessTimeSeries',
fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
features: cloudinessCollection,
xProperty: 'date',
yProperties: ['cloudiness']

})

var chartStyle = {
title: 'Sentinel Mean Cloudiness (Oct - Nov 2021)',
hAxis: {
title: 'Date',
},
vAxis: {
title: 'Mean Cloudiness',
}
};

chart.setOptions(chartStyle);
print(chart)

// code to find daily mean cloudiness

// make new collection to filter just dates and cloudiness
var cloud_dates = ee.FeatureCollection(cloudinessCollection.map(function(image){
  return ee.Feature(null, {'Date': ee.Date(image.get('date')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'), 'Cloudiness': image.get('cloudiness')})
}))

// retrieve the list of unique dates
var dates = ee.List(cloud_dates.aggregate_array('Date')).distinct()

// find mean per each day
var daily_mean_cloudiness = ee.FeatureCollection(dates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Feature(null, {'Date':date, 'Mean Cloudiness': ee.FeatureCollection(cloud_dates.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Date', date))).aggregate_mean('Cloudiness')})
}))

// plot
var meancloudiness_chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: daily_mean_cloudiness, 
  xProperty: 'Date', 
  yProperties: ['Mean Cloudiness']
})

print(meancloudiness_chart)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
